# Control sticky post date

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, sticky

When I stick a post in the backend, I want it to be added a `meta_key` and `meta_value`. In other words, to control the date when the post has been marked as sticky, I want to add a `meta_key` like `date` and a `meta_value` like `date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s')`.

I think it is possible with hook and `add_action`, but I don't know how. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Making a post sticky actually updates a blog option in WordPress background:

```
update_option('sticky_posts', $stickies); (see core in wp-includes/post.php)
```

So your hook could be pre_update_option_sticky_posts (prefix pre_update_option_ + name of the option), like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_update_option_sticky_posts', 'my_function' );
function my_function( $post_id ) { 
Your code here to save the custom field values
}
```

Comment: If I add this action in my functions.php file, with a void "my_function", and try to sticky a post from backend, it apparently save the post, but that post is not stickied... any solution?

Comment: The hook seems to be deprecated since WordPress 3.4 (it can still be used as a filter hook, though). I am a bit too busy right now to dig into this, but this is, indeed, the way to go: find the proper hook that gets triggered when saving post as sticky and execute your meta_key/meta_value within this hook. If you include the proper tests to see if your if the post was already sticky or not, you can simply use the edit_post hook:    
    `add_action( 'edit_post', 'my_function' );
    function my_function( $post_ID ) { 
 // action here
    }`

Comment: I'd like to do the following: if the post was sticky and then is unstickyed, my_function should delete the date info. If, instead, the post was not sticky and I stick it, then the date info meta key is added.

Comment: Based on your answer I've done this way and it works: `add_action( 'edit_post', 'sticky_mod' );
function sticky_mod( $post_id ) { 
    $expiring = date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s' );
    if (!is_sticky($post_ID)){
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'date', $expiring, true );
 } else {
  delete_post_meta ($post_id, 'date' );
 }
}`. The only problem is that this action runs every time I save a post, also if the sticky is not touched. However, it works.